# Pipe stdin to child process with node.js

Tags: node.js, bash

Say I have a node.js script like so:

```
import * as cp from 'child_process'

process.stdin.resume().on('data', d => {

   if(d === 'shell'){
     const k = cp.spawn('bash');
     process.stdin.pipe(k.stdin);
   }

});
```

this might work technically, but I am not sure if it makes sense. I believe it will pipe stdin of the parent process to the subprocess too? Is there a better way to do what I want to do?

IOW, initially stdin controls what the parent process is doing, but if "shell" is typed, I want stdin to only be sent to the child, and then if the user uses "ctrl-c" then stdin would be sent back to the parent again? That's basically the behavior I am looking for.

Comment: The script you've provided will spawn another child process every time the data event fires on stdin. I don't think that's the same thing that you're describing.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that really doesn't have to do with the nature of the question does it? Assume it only launches the child once, after that I don't want the parent to be listening to stdin, only the child listens to stdin. I am not sure if it's possible or if it makes much send in the world of shells but maybe.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`stream.unpipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_unpipe_destination).

Comment: How might one use that in this context?  `process.stdin.resume().unpipe()`, and then `process.stdin.pipe(k.stdin)` afterwards?